# Uvicorn + logging basic config example

Tags: python-3.x, logging, uvicorn

I have a logger that is used by my app:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s [%(name)s]: %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

In addition, in the same `__main__.py` I'm setting up my uvicorn logs:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"]["default"]["fmt"] = "%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelprefix)s %(message)s"
    LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"]["access"]["fmt"] = '%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelprefix)s %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s'

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=3001)
```

The problem is that `uvicorn.error` logs are printed duplicates.
I understand why it happens, but I don't understand what is the right way to change it:

1. Can I define a basicConfig for all the logs except `uvicorn.error`? (If I don't use BasicConfig, all my app logs are not printed)
2. Should I set `uvicorn.error` Propagate = False? If so - I didn't find a way
3. Is there a way to make my app use the uvicorn logger?

So, the basic question is what is the right way to avoid my duplicate logs.

Comment: I found this open issue but with no results:

https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/1285